# (STDERR) TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'substr'

Tags: javascript, meteor, discourse, cfs

I'm trying to parse a local CSV file，and the parse process in Meteor bootstrap

```
    var csvStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("csv", {
        path: "countrycode.csv", //optional, default is "/cfs/files" path within app container
        // transformWrite: myTransformWriteFunction, //optional
        // transformRead: myTransformReadFunction, //optional
        // maxTries: 1 //optional, default 5
    });

    var Csv = new FS.Collection("csv", {
        stores: [csvStore]
    });
    Papa.parse(Csv, {
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        }
    });
```

error msg

```
=> Exited with code: 8
W20151220-11:33:05.127(8)? (STDERR)           
W20151220-11:33:05.130(8)? (STDERR) /Users/apple/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151220-11:33:05.130(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20151220-11:33:05.131(8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20151220-11:33:05.172(8)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'substr'
W20151220-11:33:05.173(8)? (STDERR)     at guessLineEndings (packages/harrison_papa-parse/baby-parse.js:488:1)
W20151220-11:33:05.173(8)? (STDERR)     at ParserHandle.parse (packages/harrison_papa-parse/baby-parse.js:291:1)
W20151220-11:33:05.173(8)? (STDERR)     at Object.CsvToJson [as parse] (packages/harrison_papa-parse/baby-parse.js:79:1)
W20151220-11:33:05.173(8)? (STDERR)     at server/bootstrap.js:54:7
```

why the forums.meteor.com cannot visited 
[the connected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeymt.png)

Answer (score 0):

in there GFW ,to visit forums.meteor.com can use vpn,now it is ok.

like this url : http://aberration.meteor.com

meteor host deny to upload, so chose a local